# installer created with intall4j is not able to launch the application

Tags: java, macos, java-7, install4j

I have created installer by selecting OpenJdk in jre option.
Application icon blinks on the dockbar and goes and after that nothing happens.

Below is the cosole log.

```
5/23/13 11:16:47.777 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.502[154]: ([0x0-0x92092].com.install4j.9409-6211-0940-9008.25[800]) Exited with code: 1 5/23/13
11:17:09.166 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.502[154]: ([0x0-0x93093].com.install4j.9409-6211-0940-9008.25[802]) Exited with code: 1 5/23/13 
11:17:12.400 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.502[154]: ([0x0-0x94094].com.install4j.9409-6211-0940-9008.25[804]) Exited with code: 1
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you bundle a JRE? What version of Mac OS X and install4j do you use?

Comment: I have not bundled jre but I have checked "Installed Open JDK JRE(Java 7 and higher)" as you said on my previous question

Mac Informaiton
===============
OS X 10.8.2,
2.5 GHZ Intel Core i5,
4 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

Install4j Information
=====================
Install4j Multi-Platform Edition 5.1.5 (build 5568

Comment: Please contact support for a new build, this may be fixed there.

Comment: build 5568 is the last build so I can not update it to other build.

Comment: I meant a non-public build of the next version

Comment: @IngoKegel so it was a bug? Which you fixed?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen It may be related to a recent bug fix

Comment: @IngoKegel Same problem it is still not working I have installed install4j Multiplatform Edition 5.1.6 (build 5591)
=================================
'code'([0x0-0x2ff2ff].com.install4j.9409-6211-0940-9008.25[7091]) Exited with code: 1 5/24/13 5:05:14.510 PM
com.apple.launchd.peruser.502[146]: ([0x0-0x300300].com.install4j.9409-6211-0940-9008.25[7094]) Exited with code: 1 5/24/13 5:05:20.590 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.502[146]: ([0x0-0x301301].com.install4j.9409-6211-0940-9008.25[7096]) Exited with code: 1'code'